# Problems with Navigation Controller (back button and prepareForSegue)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, segue

I promise that I'm completely new to Xcode and Swift, so I know I am making silly mistakes but I don't know where. This is part of my iOS app storyboard:

[image]

where the segue between the first table view and the second navigation controller is called `myTaskDetailSegue` and its type is `Show (e.g. Push)`. Now I have some problems:

1. Neither in the first table view controller nor in the second the back button is showed and I don't know why. Many people told me that navigation bar and back button are as default in navigation controllers but they did not appear
2. In the class of the first table view controller here is the method prepareForSegue()

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

       if (segue.identifier == "myTaskDetailSegue" ) {
           let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
           let task = self.taskCollection[indexPath!.row] as Task

           let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailsMyTasksViewController

           controller.detailItem = task

           println("segue mostra task \(task.id)")
           controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
       }
   }
   ```

so you can read that the segue identifier is correct but when a row is tapped nothing happens and the second table view controller is not showed.

I don't really know what I am missing because of my inexperience.

Here is the complete storyboard:

[image: complete storyboard2]

Comment: What is the purpose of two `UINavigationViewControllers`?

Comment: I think they are needed to have a navigation bar and back buttons...both in the first table view and in the second...is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, you only need a single navigation controller at the "top" of the stack

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not understanding...why do I need one?

Comment: Because the navigation controller manages all of the view controllers that appear under it. When you push a new scene you are pushing it onto the existing navigation stack. The reason you don't get a back button is because you are pushing a new stack of controllers, so your pushed scene is the top and there is nowhere to go back to.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials if you search Google, but even the class reference explains how it works pretty well https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need two `UINavigationController`'s to what you want to achieve. Is important to note that every time you **push**(with a segue or manually) a new `UIViewController` it's added to the navigation stack.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/):

> Pushing a view controller displays its view in the navigation interface and updates the navigation controls accordingly. You typically push a view controller in response to user actions in the current view controller—for example, in response to the user tapping a row in a table.

So you can remove the second `UINavigationController` in your Storyboard and make the segue directly to your `DetailsMyTaskViewController` and update your `prepareForSegue` like in the following way:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if (segue.identifier == "myTaskDetailSegue" ) {

       let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
       let task = self.taskCollection[indexPath!.row] as Task

       let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsMyTasksViewController

       controller.detailItem = task
       println("segue mostra task \(task.id)")
   }
}
```

And your back button should appear by default as you said before. Nevertheless I strongly recommend you read the following two guides :

- [UINavigationViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)
- [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)

For a better understanding of the navigation stack, etc.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank for your help Victor but it still doesn't work, neither the segue nor the back button is showed... what can I do to discover the error?

Comment: Are you remove you second `UINavigationController` and then added the push segue from the cell to the `DetailsMyTaskViewController`?

Comment: Ok, I've just done it all over again...now the segue works perfectly and I see a back button from the second table view controller to the first but still a second back button misses (the one from the first table view controller)

Comment: @LoryLory You will never see a back button in the first `UITableViewController` it's yout `rootViewController`, the first in the navigation stack, where it goes then?

Comment: Ehm...I don't think so. I have just uploaded a screenshot of the complete storyboard. The first was just a fragment. So, according to what you have said...I just need one navigation controller right? And I am supposed to put it after the login screenshot and before the tab bar controller, right?

Comment: Yes, is correct, but remenber depends of how your transition its defined.

Comment: ehm...what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88848/discussion-between-victor-sigler-and-lory-lory).